# Cargar dato en label por JS

Tags: javascript

Necesito poner el dato del usuario según su numero de empleado, con lo siguiente estoy trayendo los datos,los cuales manda sin ningún problema con el `console.log`

```
 var tipo_usuario = jsonParse.user.type_employee;
         var numEmployee = jsonParse.user.number_employee;
         var name = jsonParse.user.firstName_employee;
         console.log(name);
         console.log(tipo_usuario);
         console.log(numEmployee);
         if(tipo_usuario == "admin")
         {
             console.log('article');
                document.getElementById("name").value = name;
                window.location.href='./article.html';
         }
```

En el html al label le puse el id de name, el cual quiere completar con la información extraída, eso lo intento con

```
document.getElementById("name").value = name;
```

Pero me marca un error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Html:

```html
        <span class="clear"> <span class="block m-t-xs"> <strong class="font-bold"><label id="name">aqui se debe poner el dato</label></strong>
```

Como puedo solucionar esto.

Comment: Intenta con `document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;`

Comment: Tambien intente eso y sigue dando el mismo error... no es necesario ponerlo como parametro verdad?

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML para ver mejor donde esta el error.

Comment: necesitamos el html

Comment: agrega como tienes definido tu HTML

Comment: Pues a mi si me funciona con `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = al;
```

para cambiarle algo

Answer (score 0):

en los labels se consigue el texto con el metodo .textContent
por lo tanto

```
document.getElementById("name").textContent = "VALOR";
```

Comment: Continua el mismo error  :/

Comment: esta sin 'display:none'? por que con textContent se accede y modifica el valor de un label, checa si se encuentra en el dom

Answer (score 0):

Si bien con `innerHTML` funciona, es más recomendable utilizar `textContent`, por dos motivos principales:

1. Rendimiento: `textContent` es más eficiente
2. Seguridad: con `textContent` evitas posibles ataques XSS

[Fuente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerText):

> Element.innerHTML returns HTML, as its name indicates. Sometimes
>   people use innerHTML to retrieve or write text inside an element, but
>   textContent has better performance because its value is not parsed as
>   HTML. Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS attacks.

Ejemplo:

```js
let jsonParse = {"user":{"type_employee":"admin","number_employee":"1","firstName_employee":"Pepe"}};
console.log(jsonParse);
var tipo_usuario = jsonParse.user.type_employee;
 var numEmployee = jsonParse.user.number_employee;
 var name = jsonParse.user.firstName_employee;
 console.log(name);
 console.log(tipo_usuario);
 console.log(numEmployee);
 if(tipo_usuario == "admin")
 {
    console.log('article');
    document.getElementById("name").textContent = name;
    document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML = name;
 }
```

```html
<span class="clear"> 
<span class="block m-t-xs"> 
<strong class="font-bold">
<label id="name">aqui se debe poner el dato</label>
<br/>
<label id="name2">aqui se debe poner el dato</label>
</strong>
```